# Getting a user name through java script in sharepoint aspx page

Tags: sharepoint

I am using Microsoft Office 365 (Plan P1). I have a user "ABC". I want that whenever ABC logs in, he is redirected to a specific site let's say Marketing site.

I am writing a javascript code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

if(document.getElementById('<%=LoginName1.ClientID %>') == "ABC"; 
location.href="/teamsite/Home.aspx";

</script>
```

But I am getting error that code blocks not allowed. Can someone help?

---

Below is the code of page:

```
<%-- _lcid="1033" _version="14.0.4762" _dal="1" --%>
<%-- _LocalBinding --%>
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="BaseName" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" title="loc:TitleBar" id="TitleBar" AllowLayoutChange="false" AllowPersonalization="false"><ZoneTemplate>
    <WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart runat="server" AllowEdit="True" AllowConnect="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Title="Web Part Page Title Bar" IsIncluded="True" Dir="Default" IsVisible="True" AllowMinimize="False" ExportControlledProperties="True" ZoneID="TitleBar" ID="g_771de8f3_6bde_473c_ade0_fd62f3baa052" HeaderTitle="Calculating..." AllowClose="False" FrameState="Normal" ExportMode="All" AllowRemove="False" AllowHide="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" DetailLink="" ChromeType="None" HelpLink="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageSmall="" HelpMode="Modeless" FrameType="None" AllowZoneChange="True" PartOrder="1" Description="" PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{771DE8F3-6BDE-473C-ADE0-FD62F3BAA052}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart>

<WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart runat="server" AllowEdit="True" AllowConnect="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Title="Web Part Page Title Bar" IsIncluded="True" Dir="Default" IsVisible="True" AllowMinimize="False" ExportControlledProperties="True" ZoneID="TitleBar" ID="g_ea882083_ab10_4e70_9986_6cbe1640086a" HeaderTitle="Calculating..." AllowClose="False" FrameState="Normal" ExportMode="All" AllowRemove="False" AllowHide="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" DetailLink="" ChromeType="None" HelpLink="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageSmall="" HelpMode="Modeless" FrameType="None" AllowZoneChange="True" PartOrder="2" Description="" PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{EA882083-AB10-4E70-9986-6CBE1640086A}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart>

</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
Div.ms-titleareaframe {
height: 100%;
}
.ms-pagetitleareaframe table {
background: none;
}
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
// ]]>
</script>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent ID="WebPartPageHideQLStyles" UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<style type="text/css">
body #s4-leftpanel {
display:none;
}
.s4-ca {
margin-left:0px;
}
</style>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server"
    ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
<div height="100%" class="ms-pagemargin"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="10" height="1" alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
            </tr>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</script>
    </table>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserData, "sp.js");   
var context = null; 
var web = null; 
var currentUser = null; 
    function getUserData() { 
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        web = context.get_web(); 
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser(); 
        currentUser.retrieve(); 
        context.load(web); 
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUserDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUserDataFailure)); 
    } 
    function onUserDataSuccess(sender, args) { 
        var user = web.get_currentUser(); 
        alert('User name:' + user.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + userObject.get_loginName()); 
    } 
    function onUserDataFailure(sender, args) { 
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
    } 
</script>
</asp:Content>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `<% ... %>` which is C# code and cannot be used in JavaScript alone.

To get the current user's login name you will need to make use of the SharePoint ECMA script object model. To get the login name you can use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserData, "sp.js");  
    var context = null;
    var web = null;
    var currentUser = null;
        function getUserData() {
            context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = context.get_web();
            currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
            currentUser.retrieve();
            context.load(web);
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUserDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUserDataFailure));
        }
        function onUserDataSuccess(sender, args) {
            var user = web.get_currentUser();
            alert('User name:' + user.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + userObject.get_loginName());
        }
        function onUserDataFailure(sender, args) {
            alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
</script>
```

The important line is `web.get_currentUser()` which is the current user and afterwards you can do `user.get_title()`. Exactly in that `onUserDataSuccess` function you can do your redirect then.

Comment: I have placed this code to test. I am getting the below erorr:

    Error
    Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.
    Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
    Correlation ID: 8ecdacf7-1ffa-4392-8ebc-90cc6fa5d55e
    Date and Time: 1/9/2012 9:03:57 AM

I have tried asp:content tag too

Comment: You probably accidently have some markup outside of the <asp:Content controls. Open your page back up and ensure that all code except the <%@ directives are within an <asp:Content block.

Comment: I have checked no code is out side the <asp:content></asp:content> block.

Comment: Ensure that the <asp:Content> tags are properly capitalized. SharePoint seems to freak out when <asp:content> tag is found. ;-)

Comment: I have checked that too - only <asp:Content> is used with a capital 'C'. I have reread the code twice and now pasting it below:

Comment: I have added the page code in my original post - please help!

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaMoin You can't just add a new `<asp:Content>` to your page, you will need to use **ContentPlaceHolders**! Put your code in `PlaceHolderMain` - that is the main Placeholder. All the others you almost don't need. You should read up on how to create web site pages.